# What is the best way to save map pins so that user can come back to the pins that were previously created using Swift?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I have a map where a user can create pins by a long press recognizer. When a pin is opened, it opens an annotation view with a button. If that button is pressed, it segues into another viewController. That last viewController has a button that allows the user to segue back into the map. When this is done, however, the map opens with none of the pins that the user had created. What would be the best way to save the pins that the user has created?

Answer (score 0):

Store your lat and lon data in an array and in viewDidAppear method loop your array of coordinates to reload your annotations.